# Display sub-tasks and sections in calendar

Tags: asana

It appears that only 'normal' tasks are displayed in the calendar. Sub-tasks and sections, even though they can be assigned dates, will not show up in calendars.

This is more a feature request, but I figure this is the best place for it.

EDIT:

It appears that the team calendar does not have sections, even when they are assigned to people in the team. It also does not have sub-tasks.

The per-project calendar does have sections, but does not have sub-tasks.

Sub-tasks don't appear in the per-project or team calendars, but they DO show up in the all-tasks calendar. The all-tasks calendar does not have sections...

I think we just need consistent task inclusion across all calendars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the admins of StackOverflow tend to delete questions not related to programming. If you want to make feature suggestions, [support](https://asana.com/support) is generally the best place to do so - they also collate feature requests and make sure the ones that are frequently requested bubble up.